# can't inflate gridview content, got null pointer exception error

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview

hye, i'm a newb at android programming, so i need help on my project

i was trying to create a gridview inside tab layout by inflating the gridview, and then inflating the gridview content but it seems not working and i can't find the solution, thanks to anyone who want to help me.

so here's my mainactivity code

this code contain my tabs:

```js
package id.WKKR.ktcafe;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import gridAdapter.CafeAdapter;
import tabs.SlidingTabLayout;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MenuUtama extends ActionBarActivity{

 
 Toolbar toolbar;
 private ViewPager mPager;
 private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
 private GridView makananGrid;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_utama);
  
  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  NavDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavDrawerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
  drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);
  
  mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.MyPager);
  mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
  
  mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyTabs);
  mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
  mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabsText);
  mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
  mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.brown));
  
  mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
      
        //the problem is here, i got null pointer exception error
  makananGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
  makananGrid.setAdapter(new MyCafe(this));
  

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_utama, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "This Is " + item.getTitle() + " Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return true;
  }
  
  if (id == R.id.bill) {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, BillTagihanAnda.class));
  }
  
  if (id == R.id.pesanan) {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, DaftarPesananAnda.class));
  }
  
  if (id == R.id.callwaiter){
   startActivity(new Intent(this, PanggilPelayan.class));
   finish();
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
 
 class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
  
  int icon[] = {R.drawable.ic_food, R.drawable.ic_drink,R.drawable.ic_desserts};
  String[] tabsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
  

  public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
   super(fm);
   tabsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
   
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);
   return myFragment;
  }
  
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(icon[position]);
   drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
   ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
   SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");
   spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   
   return spannableString;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return 3;
  }
  
 }
 
 public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  private TextView textView;
  private GridView myGridView;

  public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
   MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putInt("position", position);
   myFragment.setArguments(args);
   return myFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    @Nullable ViewGroup container,
    @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
   textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
   myGridView = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
   Bundle bundle = getArguments();
   if (bundle != null)
   {
    textView.setText("The Page Selected is "+bundle.getInt("position"));

//i was trying to set the adapter here but always got an error, and i don't know why.
    myGridView.setAdapter(new MyCafe(this));

   }

   return layout;
  }
 }
```

and here's my adapter which inflate the gridview content:

```js
class Menus {
  int imageId = 0;
  String menus = "";
  String menusPrices = "";

  Menus(int imageId, String menus, String menusPrices) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.menus = menus;
    this.menusPrices = menusPrices;
  }
}

class MyCafe extends BaseAdapter {

  ArrayList < Menus > list;
  Context context;

  MyCafe(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    list = new ArrayList < Menus > ();
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    String[] tempMenusNames = res.getStringArray(R.array.food);
    String[] tempMenusPrices = res.getStringArray(R.array.foodprices);
    int[] menusImages = {
      R.drawable.makanana, R.drawable.makananb,
        R.drawable.makananc, R.drawable.makanand,
        R.drawable.makanane, R.drawable.makananf
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      Menus tempMenus = new Menus(menusImages[i], tempMenusNames[i],
        tempMenusPrices[i]);
      list.add(tempMenus);
    }

  }

  public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
  }

  public Object getItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(i);
  }

  public long getItemId(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return i;
  }

  class ViewHolder {
    ImageView myMenus;
    TextView myMenusText;
    TextView MyMenusPrice;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
      myMenus = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      myMenusText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      MyMenusPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
  }

  public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, viewGroup, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder(row);
      row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Menus temp = list.get(i);
    holder.myMenus.setImageResource(temp.imageId);
    holder.myMenusText.setText(temp.menus);
    holder.MyMenusPrice.setText(temp.menusPrices);

    return row;
  }

}
}
```

here's my activity_menu_utama.xml :

```js
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="id.WKKR.ktcafe.MenuUtama" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <tabs.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/MyTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/MyPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="id.WKKR.ktcafe.NavDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_nav_drawer_fragment"
        yourapp:layout="@layout/activity_nav_drawer_fragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here's my error logcat :

```js
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): Process: id.WKKR.ktcafe, PID: 4347
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {
  id.WKKR.ktcafe / id.WKKR.ktcafe.MenuUtama
}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2318)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2396)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 139)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1293)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 149)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5257)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 515)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 793)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 609)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at id.WKKR.ktcafe.MenuUtama.onCreate(MenuUtama.java: 66)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 5411)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1087)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2270)
05 - 05 14: 43: 40.576: E / AndroidRuntime(4347): ...11 more
```

Comment: Show your `activity_menu_utama` xml.

Comment: Can you also post the logcat of the exception and also mention the line that is throwing the exception?

Comment: the activity_menu_utama.xml added, please take a look @Ircover

Comment: i'll add the logcat, please wait @PrerakSola

Comment: @PrerakSola, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no view in your xml with `gridView` id, so `findViewById(R.id.gridView)` returns null. Add GridView with `android:id="@+id/gridView"` to your xml or don't try to get it in your code.

Comment: it works, the gridview now showing, but there's a problem with the tab sliding, so i disabled the onCreateView in MyFragmentClass, but still unable to swipe to left and right, i have to press the tabs instead, any suggestion?

Comment: Is [it](http://javahow.net/questions/28297614/slidingtablayout-tabs-not-clickable) your problem?

Comment: nope not that one, what i'm trying to do is create gridview inside each tab layout (3 layout in my case), with your help i was able to get the gridview work, but the other problem pop up, i can't swipe to left or right to change the tabs, but i can tap on the tab to change between tabs.

Comment: I can't help you with that. Create new question for it.